# Submit automatically without delay?

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I'm following MVC structure and I've run into a problem when opening a search page where data is being loaded and the user has the ability to search.

The problem is that the user has to press the submit button so that the View-layer on the search site can send the form's input name-values to the controller. The Controller then binds those name values to variables and connect them with the model object.

Here is some of code:

View-layer:

```
      <form id="submitForm" name="submitFrom" method="POST" action onload="SearchController.php">
        <p>
            Personnummer:<br /> <input type="text" name="Personnummer_search" id="Personnummer_search" /><br />

            Namn:<br /> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />

          <input type="submit" name="button" id="btn_search" value="Sök"/>

<table class="table table-hover">
        <tr class="danger">
            <td>Personnummer</td>
            <td>Namn</td>
</tr>
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Results); $i++) {
            echo "
             <tr>
            <td>{$Results[$i]['Personnummer']}</td>
            <td>{$Results[$i]['Namn']}</td>
</tr>
```

My controller layer

```
  include 'c:/wamp/www/mvc/model/Sok.php';

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $Personnummer =$_POST['Personnummer_search'];
 $displayResults = new Sok($name, $Personnummer');
 $Results = $displayResults->getSearchResult();
```

When the page loads I get error "*Undefined index: name*"  "*Undefined index: name*"
It's because the form haven't been sent to the controller so there is nothing to bind the variables in the Controller-layer. When the user clicks on submit, everything works perfectly because then the form input name-values(`$_POST['Personnummer_search']`) gets sent to the controller and can bind it to the variables.

Is there anyway to send the form to the controller without having to press the submit button?
I've tried Onload click function but there is a delay before sending the form, meaning error occurs for a while before it works normally

Answer (score 1):

what you can do, if you are using jquery is this:

```
$("#submitForm").find("input").bind("change", function(){

    // ajax function

});
```

or with plain javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var inputs =document.getElementById("submitForm").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener("change",function(){
            console.log("ajax method here");
        }, false);
    }
},false);
```